# Advanced mongodb collection sorting

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I need a help for some advanced collection sorting in mongodb. Suppose that we have the database local and we have the following model:

collection continent with documents 
{"_id":1,"name":"Europe"},{"_id":2,"name":"Asia"},{"_id":3,"name":"North America"},
{"_id":4,"name":"South America"},{"_id":5,"name":"Australia"},{"_id":6,"name":"Africa"}

collection country with documents
{"_id":1,"name":"France","populationInMillions":66,"continent":DBRef("continent",1,"local"),"cities":[{"name":"Paris"},{"name":"Marseille"},{"name":"Toulouse"}]},

{"_id":2,"name":"Spain","populationInMillions":47,"continent":DBRef("continent",1,"local"),"cities":[{"name":"Madrid"},{"name":"Seville"},{"name":"Valencia"}]},

{"_id":3,"name":"China","populationInMillions":1360,"continent":DBRef("continent",2,"local"),"cities":[{"name":"Beijing"},{"name":"Chongqing"},{"name":"Shanghai"}]},

{"_id":4,"name":"Brazil","populationInMillions":200,"continent":DBRef("continent",4,"local"),"cities":[{"name":"Sao Paulo"},{"name":"Rio de Janeiro"},{"name":"Salvador"}]}

So when we want to sort countries by some simple criteria like populationInMillions descending, we will use query:
db.country.find({}).sort({ populationInMillions:-1 })

My question is what if we want to sort by some complex criteria like some of the following 
(Some of them in this example make sense in the real world context, some make not sense, but the focus is on the technical solution.
I have to apply similar solutions in a real world project.)

Sort countries:
1. by the name of their continent (consider that we don't have subobject but DBRef)

2. in a way that the countries with populationInMillions bigger than 1000 are located before the other countries
3. by the total number of characters in all the names of its cities (example for france : Paris (5 chars), Marseille (9 chars), Toulouse (8 chars) - total 22 chars)
4. alphabetically by the name of the second city of a country (in this example Marseille for France, Seville for Spain and so on)

If you have answer for all or some of those questions, please help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just want to add that if you have to use stored javascript functions, those solutions are also acceptable.

Comment: What have you done so far?? SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I can do all those things in sql without big effort, so I just want to know can I also do this in mongo. I put this simplified data model because I didn't want to complicate with real world example I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the way the document is stored currently, I believe the solutions will either be expensive or impossible as more sorting are added based on the relationship of these two collections, especially when paging is involved. I suggest that you put continent information into country collection. MongoDB is designed to be denormalized, better take advantage of that.

**1 - Sorting country by continent name:**

1. Pull out FULL list of continents in desired order.
2. Using the continent's `_id`, you'll then pull out list of countries, likely using `$in` operator.
3. Map the two lists together using `HashMap`

*Issue : Paging is almost impossible to do in this case. It is inefficient, duplicate result is possible and you are unlikely to be able to sort the countries themselves, only continents' name can be sorted on.*

**2 - Sorting with priority to countries with counts above 1000 first**

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with this one. Sorting by population count seems to solve this issue nicely. However, If you need something like:

```
|----------------|
|populationCount |
|----------------|
|2500            |
|2030            |
|2110            |
|2666            |
|1999            |
|800             |
|600             |
|700             |
|----------------|
```

For this, you may add a weight column to your countries collection. For all the countries that exceeds a certain number of `populationInMillions` (1000, in your case), set  it to a higher weight, and the rest to lower weight. That way you can sort it using `db.Countries.sort({weight : -1})` or `db.Countries.sort({weight : -1, populationInMillions : -1})`, if you need to. It will be something like this:

```
|----------------|------|
|populationCount |weight|
|----------------|------|
|2500            |2     |
|2030            |2     |
|2110            |2     |
|2666            |2     |
|1999            |2     |
|800             |1     |
|600             |1     |
|700             |1     |
|----------------|------|
```

**3 - Sorting by total number of characters in names of all its cities.**

I don't think there's a way in MongoDB to perform that query on the fly but since city names do not change, you can instead store the total character count when you add or remove a city from a country. That way you may sort with that column. Simple to execute and sorting can be indexed. Performance friendly.

**4 - Alphabetically by the name of the second city.**

I have no idea what this means. Any examples?

*p/s : When there's a requirement to sort something, try to make sure the criteria reside in one collection for easier querying.*

Comment: First I want to thank you for the detailed and helpfull answer. Let me explain you a real world case for the example number 4. I have collection of sport competitions and every competiton has an array of its names in different languages. I want to sort competitons by their names but based on the request I dynamically decide by which language I sort competitions. That is the exact scenario from the example number 4.

Comment: You can sort it using `db.Sports.find().sort({"sportLanguage.n.name" : 1})` , where _n_ is the position of your desired language.

It has a few drawbacks :
1. You must enter different languages in similar order for all competitions.
2. The sorting might be inaccurate due to several maybe unavoidable factors, i.e., different number of languages for all competitions.

I'd prefer to have separate columns for different names in different languages. Less headache imo but I could be wrong. Never had this scenario =]

Comment: Separate columns for different languages are not acceptable because there is always posibility of adding new language which would lead to the data model changing. All mongo collections are mapped to the classes on the service layer so it would be neccessery to change classes also by adding new fields. But your firs explanation in a combination with storing some default values for missing languages would be enough I think. Then all competitons would have all translations in the consistend order. Thank you very much once more!

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree that normalization should be avoided in mongodb and in the examples above we should put the continent as a subobject of the country so we can easily filter and sort countries by the continent.

In the previous answer there were some good suggestions to realize tasks by adding new fields to the data model. After some mongodb research I have found one more way to achieve the result without really changing data model. The solution uses aggregation. Let's take a look to the example 2 (sort countries in a way that the countries with populationInMillions bigger than 1000 are located before the other countries). This type of solution can generally be applied for many other custom sorting criteria:

```
db.country.aggregate( [
   { $project: 
        { _id: "$_id",  
            name : "$name",
            populationInMillions : "$populationInMillions",
            cities : "$cities",
            populationRank: { $cond: { if: { $gt : [ "$populationInMillions" , 1000 ] }, then: 0 , else: 1 }} 
        }
    },
    { $sort : {'populationRank' : 1 /*, 'anotherField1' : -1, 'anotherField2' : 1*/} },
    { $project : { /*We can skip this projection if we don't want to exclude populationRank from the result*/ 
            _id : "$_id", 
            name : "$name", 
            populationInMillions : "$populationInMillions", 
            cities : "$cities" } 
    }
] );
```

For the example number 3 (by the total number of characters in all the names of its cities) we unfortunately don't have a $strlen function, but it will be added in the future mongodb versions. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5319
But if we suppose that we already have $strlen function, here is the interesting solution for the example number 3 which also can give an idea for the other custom sorting criteria which does not rely on strlen:

```
db.country.aggregate(
    [ { $unwind : "$cities" },
        { $group : { 
            _id : "$_id", 
            name : { $max : "$name" }, 
            populationInMillions : { $max : "$populationInMillions" }, 
            cities : { $push : "$cities" }, 
            citiesCharCount : { $sum : { $strlen : "$cities.name" } } } },
        { $sort : { citiesCharCount : 1 } },
        { $project : { /*We can skip this projection if we don't want to exclude citiesCharCount from the result*/  
            _id : "$_id", 
            name : "$name", 
            populationInMillions : "$populationInMillions", 
            cities : "$cities" } 
        }
    ]
);
```

Without strlen function there are solutions based on the mapResuce and custom javascript functions https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/

Comment: I think the aggregation approach is brilliantly written but depending on the size of the dataset and expected response time, it might not be ideal to use. Without a pipeline that can utilize index like `$match`, you will effectively be reading every document in that collection. It can become very slow as size of documents grow. Though I do like the fact that you'll no longer need to do have application side code to maintain the weight. Nice work.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I am novice to nosql databases so my mindset is relational oriented at the moment and when I for example have situation in sql that I have a table person with columns first_name and last_name and when I want to sort persons for example by their initials, I would make a query 

"select first_name, last_name  from person
order by substr(first_name, 1, 1) || substr(last_name, 1, 1)"

It would not make sense to maintain another column initials in the persons table because in a few scenarios you need to sort by the initials.
I will track performances anyway.